# Identify component from hard drive PCB

Tags: pcb, power-electronics, identification, hard-drive

Can someone tell me the value of this component? The component is from a hard drive PCB.

[image: component]

[image: component2]

Comment: Why is this tagged "arduino" (not related to Arduino at all), "pcb" (the question has nothing to do with the PCB) and "power electronics" (it's for a low-voltage, low-powered hard-drive)? What is the component designation? Is it D4 indicating that it's a diode?

Comment: @ayobkimo These pictures are not good. The first is cut off. The second is not clear what the markings on the part are. Please record the numbers and any markings of each part underneath the picture and provide clear pictures of the part with the silkscreen on the part clearly visible.

Comment: What do you do with this information? Most likely if you replace this part with another one, it will burn up too, unless the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classic burned component on a hard drive PCB which looks like a diode, is a TVS diode.

Once common cause of such damage on 3.5" HDDs is where someone has managed to reverse its 4-pin "Molex" power input connector. In that case 5 V is connected to the HDD 12 V power input, and **12 V is connected to the HDD 5 V power input**. Whatever over-voltage protection exists on the HDD PCB's 5 V rail, is then connected to the 12 V supply.

We can't read the markings on the burned component. However the photo of the undamaged component which you included (presumably from a similar, but undamaged, HDD?) shows an ON Semi component in a package-type used for diodes, with the top marking "QA". That does match an [On Semi NSA5.0AT3G 5V TVS diode](http://web.archive.org/web/20150710103005/http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NSA5.0A-D.PDF):

[image: Image from On Semi NSA5.0AT3G datasheet showing QA top marking]

If you can read the top markings from the burned component, and if it matches a [known marking of a 5 V TVS diode](https://community.wd.com/t/hdd-tvs-diode-faq/14692), and if the component is across the 5 V rail on the PCB, then this would all help to confirm that the burned component is indeed a 5 V TVS. Overloaded TVS diodes tend to fail short-circuit.

There can be additional damage (either damaged components and/or damaged PCB tracks) on the PCB, depending on the HDD manufacturer's PCB design. That sort of repair topic is generally off-topic on this site, but you can read more in the link above, and by searching for web pages with terms like `hard drive pcb tvs diode`.